# Checkbox and radio buttons are clickable from outside area in responsive touch devices, How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, bootstrap-4, radio-button

In touch screen responsive devices, if I click outside the checkbox or radio button (within approx. 8px area) checkbox and radio buttons are toggled from outside area also.
This is happening only in case of responsive touch devices. It is totally working fine in desktop.
The issue is of native html form elements and it exist everywhere. I checked it on bootstrap website and some other sites as well.

If someone have any solution to reduce this clickable area. Please suggest. It would be really appreciable.

Steps to check this issue :

- Open Bootstrap website and navigate to checkboxes : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#checkboxes-and-radios
- Open the developer console. Switch to responsive view in emulator
- Try to click outside the checkbox
- Checkbox is clickable from outside area also. I want to reduce that area.

Answer (score 1):

You mean inside the gray area you're still able to click the radio/checkbox? Yes because clickarea on touch devices need approx. 40px * 40px dimension for usability reasons. Otherwise people need to zoom in, in order to touch it properly.

On another note:
If you don't use the responsive view but simply resize to mobile, you have the same view but with a pointer. It's easier for you to aim the mouse around the checkbox/radio so you can miss it by a pixel. There's no issue there.

Once you switch to responsive view, the cursor is 40px by 40px, and now it's harder to miss. So what you're trying to solve is not even an issue. It's simply the cursor got bigger and the edges of the touch point are hitting the checkbox.

Never going to solve this one.

Comment: Agree with your facts @Tim, 
But in case of my design. We have an icon after the checkbox with 8px space between checkbox and icon.
In mobile phones, Now when I try to click on icon the checkbox toggled.
is there any way exist with which we can reduce the clickable area from 40px*40px to 30pxx30px in touch devices?

Comment: Can you produce a live example where this issue occurs, jsfiddle or codepen?